# MariaDB default utf8

Tags: mariadb, installation

The installation puts `character-set-server=utf8` in `my.ini` by default. Is it better to use `utf8mb4` instead of clean `utf8` and if Yes, why `utf8mb4` is not set by default?

Comment: What version are you running?

Answer (score 1):

depending on Version utf8 is a synonym for utf8mb3 or utf8mb4.

so you are always compatible with the version and you can restore a backup without problems, if the version has no utf8mb4 support

Comment: Does it mean that comparisons like `utf8 vs utf8mb4` are obsolete because `utf8` is now not the old `utf8`?

Comment: yes, mysql and mariadb replaces utf8 with the current version